# Converting Excel Column to Text using VBA ActiveX

Tags: vba, activex, activexobject

I am needing to convert a column to text format before I paste the data into the spreadsheet using javascript/VBA. Is there a way to do this using ExcelSheet.ActiveSheet or ActiveSheet.Range? I am outputting an 8 digit formatted date (MM/DD/YY) and Excel keeps changing it to M(M)/D(D)/YYYY.

Comment: `Range("...").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"`

Comment: When I use the Range("") with just column letters, it errors out, but if I include a row number on the end, it works just fine. Anyway around this so the entire column gets formatted for when I run more than 1 record through?

Comment: `Range("A:A")` for example refers to column A. `Range("A:D")` refers to columns A through D. This applies the format to the entire column.

Comment: The Range code works perfectly when displaying the data in the 8 digit format, but the data that is actually stored in the cell is not correct. Dates are still stored as mm/d/yyyy, m/dd/yyyy, etc.

Comment: A date is a formatted number. If you have something else, then you probably have text-that-looks-like-a-date.

Comment: You would be correct. Anyway around this issue?